# Text is not vertically centered in the button (Bootstrap 4.4 Safari macOS)

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

[image: text is not vertically centered (Bootstrap 4.4 Safari macOS)]

How can I fix this? I'm using Bootstrap 4.4, all button styles are default except:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap');

.btn-action {
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  padding-left: 2.5rem;
  padding-right: 2.5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.btn-yellow {
  background-color: #ffd802;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}
```

The problem is only in Safari on macOS.
HTML:

```
<div class="text-center">
  <button class="btn btn-action btn-yellow" type="button">
    Read the Story
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you at least put the HTML code?

Comment: @huanfeng I have added the details (CSS/HTML)